# Using static variables to call from different methods

Tags: c#, static

I am trying to 'share' variables between methods in C#. I am quite new to C#, I know there's no such thing as a 'global variable' and I'm not quite sure how to correctly use static variables.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectOne
{
    static bool tooHigh;
    static internal waistMeasurment;
    class Main
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetVariables();
        }

        public static void GetVariables() //This method gets the users height & waist measurments 
                                           //and calls the 'ValidateWaist' and 'ValidateHeight' methods for validation
        {
            Console.Write("What is your waist measurment? "); //This prints a string prompting the user to input their waist measurment
            waistMeasurment = Console.ReadLine(); //This writes the users input under the string 'waistMeasurment'
            ValidateWaist();
                if tooHigh ==true
                {
                waistMeasurment = Console.ReadLine();
                ValidateWaist();
                }
        }
        public static void ValidateWaist() //This method validates the user input so that it fits within the minimum bound
        {
            if (waistMeasurment < 60) //Checks the lower bound of the waist limit
            {
                Console.Write("Your waist measurment must be above 59cm? "); //Output error feedback
                tooHigh = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tooHigh = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im having issues with the tooHigh and waistMeasurment

Comment: You cannot place any members (static or not) outside a class.

Comment: .Net is a development paradigm based on *Types*.  The installed .Net framework includes a bunch of types "out of the box",  Everything in .Net is a type, there are two kinds of types, reference types (`class`s) and value types (built-ins and `struct`s).  ALL data, and code, including declared variables must be associated with a defined type in the system (inside a `class` or `struct`).  The process of writing a program is, basically creating your own custom types and putting code, and data structures into those types. In your code above,  `toohigh` and `wastemeasurement` are not in a type

Comment: You're also missing parens in your `if(tooHigh) ` statement

Comment: So instead of int I should go 'System.Int32' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static can be used to share variable but need to be declared inside Class, there were some more errors in your program, I have modified your program you can use it and debug it for learning

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static bool tooHigh;
    static int waistMeasurment;    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetVariables();
    }

    public static void GetVariables() //This method gets the users height & waist measurments 
                                      //and calls the 'ValidateWaist' and 'ValidateHeight' methods for validation
    {
        Console.Write("What is your waist measurment? "); //This prints a string prompting the user to input their waist measurment
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out waistMeasurment); //This writes the users input under the string 'waistMeasurment'
        ValidateWaist();

        if (tooHigh == true)
            {
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out waistMeasurment); ;
            ValidateWaist();
        }
    }
    public static void ValidateWaist() //This method validates the user input so that it fits within the minimum bound
    {
        if (waistMeasurment < 60) //Checks the lower bound of the waist limit
        {
            Console.Write("Your waist measurment must be above 59cm? "); //Output error feedback
            tooHigh = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tooHigh = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ah I see the errors I made, I can't name a class 'Main', alongside others. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

C# is an Object-Oriented Programming Language, which means it consists of `namespaces`, that hold `classes`and `structs`, which hold `fields` and `properties` (so, variables) and `methods`.

You're absolutely right, there are no global variables in C#. Although, you could hack together a class with a static variable and use it as a global, it's best to keep all the variables local and under control.

What you want to achieve, is to place the two variables (`tooHigh` and `waistMeasurment`) within the static `Main` class as static variables.

You also don't use `if` statements in the style of Python and `internal` was invented for methods, not variables. According to your code, you are looking for the type of `integer`, since later on, you are checking whether the variable `waistMeasurment` is less than 60. In order to do this, you first have to cast the variable to an `integer`. The proper way to this, is with the `int.TryParse` method.

```
namespace ProjectOne
{
    class Main
    {
        static bool tooHigh;
        static int waistMeasurment;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetVariables();
        }

        public static void GetVariables() //This method gets the users height & waist measurments 
                                           //and calls the 'ValidateWaist' and 'ValidateHeight' methods for validation
        {
            Console.Write("What is your waist measurment? "); //This prints a string prompting the user to input their waist measurment
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out waistMeasurment); //This writes the users input under the string 'waistMeasurment'
            ValidateWaist();
                if (tooHigh)
                {
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out waistMeasurment); 
                ValidateWaist();
                }
        }
        public static void ValidateWaist() //This method validates the user input so that it fits within the minimum bound
        {
            if ((int)waistMeasurment < 60) //Checks the lower bound of the waist limit
            {
                Console.Write("Your waist measurment must be above 59cm? "); //Output error feedback
                tooHigh = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tooHigh = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the 'internal' was a typo -> I think my IDE auto corrected my int or something along those lines, I now see how to use the TryParse, I was confused as I thought I was supposed to change its type but on another post I saw that "you don't have to change a variable type in c#, it parses itself" - which is obviously incorrect :p. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you have to change your code in order to place the variables inside a `Type`:

What you've got:

```
namespace ProjectOne
{
    static bool tooHigh;
    static internal waistMeasurment;

    class Main
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

What you have to write:

```
namespace ProjectOne
{
    class Main
    {
        static bool tooHigh;
        static internal waistMeasurment;

        //your code again
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that. Will it work if I put the variables in a class besides 'Main'? Also thanks for the help so far :)